# Please help me understand the reason for using this 5V battery and 2k resistor at the gate of this MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, amplifier, mosfet-driver, comparator

[image]

Please help me understand what that V3 source and 2k resistor are doing here. The output from the comparator U4 will form the gate voltage of MOSFET. Because of the 2k resistor, the voltage at the gate terminal should have no influence from the 5V source. I don't see why they are added in the circuit.

Comment: May depend on context you have but we don't. I would point out that an LM339 is a comparator, and comparators often have open-collector outputs, which need to be pulled up to +V in order to work. Perhaps a TLC339/5 is similar? go find its datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U4 is a comparator with an open-drain output. It needs a pull-up on the output to work, which is shown as V3 (5V) and the 2k resistor. It could have just as easily used V+ for the pull-up resistor voltage so long as V+ doesn’t exceed the 2N7000 maximum gate-source of 20V.

The comparator output will be as follows:

- ‘excitation’ < GND: output high-Z, pull up to 5V, FET on
- ‘excitation’ > GND: output low, FET off

I’m guessing that this part of the circuit is to provide a blanking / gain control function for the INA132 based on the excitation state.

Answer (score 2):

Part of your problem is the way it is drawn. Logically it will work* as drawn. Remove the battery and put R3 to the V+, at that point you can see the bias on the MOSFET which will turn it on. This change is to make the circuit a bit more understandable.  As stated previously the LM339 is a comparator with an open collector output and it needs to be pulled high to turn on the N=-Channel MOSFET. The Pull Up places a voltage on the gate causing the MOSFET to turn on. It The MOSFET is enhanced (turned on) when its minimum Vgs (Voltage gate source) is exceeded. This voltage is not the same on all 2N7000, you need to check the data sheet of the brand you are using. When the comparator has its input below ground it will hopefully driving the MOSFET gate below its Vgs threshold, in this case ground. turn off. *This comparator cannot work properly as input has a limit of -0.3, pumping current into the input can cause the output to be in the wrong state.

Answer (score 1):

Your question will move to "Why this circuitry does not use V+, in place of V3". V3 is for not more than driving U4 output high, which is open drain/collector. Thus, R3 is a pull-up. The current from"INA output" (? it sounds strange, perhaps "INA input") is measured through r4 & U5, when T1 is switched on.

Answer (score 1):

You should search online for "open collector" and "pull up." What you'll find is that a 339 comparator does a bang-up job putting out a logic 0, but needs help with 1 - crying out for it. Accordingly, it expects the circuit you asked about. Whoever drew the schematic should be commended for preserving the habitats of spotted owls. I can't think of any reason besides saving space to draw the circuit upside down from convention - might save paper.